# How to consume the export output of the Experience Builder Site Performance tool?

Tags: community, lightning-community, performance

This [Analyze and Improve Experience Builder Site Performance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_optimizer.htm&type=5) tool, a Chrome extension, includes an Export feature that outputs content that starts like this:

```
{
  "buckets":{
    "1":{
      "collected":{
        "gatherer-aura-getArtifact-[\"transactions\"]":[
          {
            "event":"transaction",
            "namespace":"aura",
            "cycle":35,
            "context":{
              "transaction":"{\"id\":\"catchAllTransaction:3\",\"ts\":161719.31,\"duration\":8059,\"pageStartTime\":1621855178211,\"marks\":{},\"context\":{\"warning\":\"THIS IS NOT THE SAME AS PAGEVIEW BY FRAMEWORK\",\"count\":3,\"isCatchAllTransaction\":true},\"owner\":null,\"unixTS\":false}",
              "memory":45718366,
              "objectCount":190,
              "componentCount":1028,
              "createdAt":1621855347989,
              "id":"catchAllTransaction:3",
              "start":161719.31,
              "end":169778.31,
              "actionsStorageSize":1182.224609375,
              "maxActionsStorageSize":153600
            }
          },
```

What is the best way to consume this data? Do you just have to write your own code for that?

Comment: I guess it's just an audit tool that you can use to analyze your site's performance and take necessary action(mostly change code). Personally, I use Lighthouse by chrome to analyze my community pages

Comment: Thanks @AnmolKumar. Will take a look at Lighthouse too.